# how to connect sql server with linux?

Tags: perl, freetds

Whenever i will run Perl code i got following error:

```
DBI connect('SQLSERVER','rti_dbuser',...) failed: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified (SQL-IM002) at /usr/WINAST/RTI/AGI/M_TEST.pl line 14
Coudn't Connect SQL at /usr/WINAST/RTI/AGI/M_TEST.pl line 14.
```

The configuration file are given below:

odbc.ini

```
[SQLSERVER]
description = Asterisk ODBC for SQL SERVER
;driver = FreeTDS 
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
server = 10.2.20.42\APSHCL
Database = RTI
port = 1433
tds_version = 9.0
try domain login = yes
try server login = yes
nt domain = DOMAIN
language = us_english
```

odbcinst.ini

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = FreeTDS ODBC driver for MSSQL
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/local/lib/libtdsS.so
FileUsage = 1
```

My code

```
use DBI;
use Data::Dumper;
use Asterisk::AGI;
my $agi = new Asterisk::AGI;
$first_param  = $ARGV[0];

my $DSN = q/dbi:ODBC:SQLSERVER/;
my $uid = q/username/;
my $pwd = q/password/;

my $DRIVER = "Freetds";
my $dbh = DBI->connect($DSN,$uid,$pwd) or die "Coudn't Connect SQL";
my $servernumber = 2;


my $sql = "EXEC usp_check_black_list '".$first_param."'" ;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

$return = $sth->fetchrow();
$agi->set_variable('result',$return);
print Dumper($return);
$sth->finish;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

whenever i'm executing my perl code, the driver is not found.I have already define the driver but it is not use that driver....

please help me...

Comment: Have you checked sites like http://www.connectionstrings.com/ ?

Comment: basically i have define by default driver for freetds in odbcinst.ini file, but it is not pick up the driver whenever i execute the Perl program.It is throwing the following error: "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified"

Comment: i have define the freetds driver directly in odbc.ini file, but i got following error: "Data source name not found, and no default driver specified" plz help me...

Comment: Seeing your question, I suppose you tried that: http://www.unixodbc.org/doc/FreeTDS.html

Comment: You should probably include the perl code which is actually generating the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using DBD::Sybase. MSSQL is a fork from the Sybase code, and DBD::Sybase still works pretty well, though YMMV.